# Is this proof of the Monty Hall problem correct?

Tags: solution-verification, monty-hall

The [Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem) can be stated as follows:

> Suppose you're on a game show, and you're given the choice of three
>   doors: Behind one door is a car; behind the others, goats. You pick a
>   door, say No. 1, and the host, who knows what's behind the doors,
>   opens another door, say No. 3, which has a goat. He then says to you,
>   "Do you want to pick door No. 2?" Is it to your advantage to switch
>   your choice?

Paul Erdös said once

> Es sei „hoffnungslos“ für jemanden, der sich in Entscheidungsbäumen
>   und mit dem Satz von Bayes nicht auskenne, die Lösung zu verstehen

which can be translated to

> Its "hopeless" for someone to understand the solution who does not
>   know about decision-making trees and the Bayes' theorem

I am surprised by this statement, because I think its possible for anyone to understand the solution without knowing Bayes' theorem. I would state my proof as follows:

You pick one of three doors at random. The probability that you hit a door with a goat is $\frac{2}{3}$. Now the gamemaster opens a different door with a goat and asks you if you want to switch. If your in front of a door with a goat, then you would win if you switch, otherwise you would lose. The question "Do you want to switch" is thus equivalent to as asking "Do you think you hit a door with a goat". Thus you would win with $\frac{2}{3}= 66.666..$% percent if you change.

Now that I read the statement form Erdös I am insecure about the above proof. Is anything about the above argument not correct? Did I implicit use Bayes' theorem? Or was Erdös simply wrong with his statement that you can't understand the goat problem without Bayes' theorem?

Comment: In a way, with the two cases where the initial door is a goat, the host is screwed. He then has only one choice for the door to open.

Comment: Erdös is surely a great mathematician, but I do not agree here with his opinion. Assuming the rules of the original game, it is clear that 1) if we change, we win, if and only if we did not choose the car-door. 2) if we do not change, we win, if and only if we chose the car-door. There is no need for Bayes.

Comment: so if Monty knows A) you picked the car and B) you know Bayes theorem - he could be trying to trick you - right?  What would you do if he didn't bother opening a door?  Some people might suspect that they had chosen the goat.

Comment: @Parcly - If monty has to open a door, then the contestant seems to have a single best strategy, which is to switch, so I agree that Monty should then lose if the contestants first choice was a goat

Comment: on the other hand if there were 1million doors, you'd know the one you chose is almost certainly incorrect, so any attempt to fool you with a stop-loss of opening all of the doors bar two is doomed to failure, since you could then take the car from the unopened door that almost certainly has to be the car

Comment: The quote is misattributed.  It appears to be a translation into German from an article by Andrew Vazsonyi, expressing Vazsonyi's conclusion based on his difficulty convincing Erdos that you should switch.  See https://web.archive.org/web/20140309021212/http://www.decisionsciences.org/DecisionLine/Vol30/30_1/vazs30_1.pdf

Comment: @BarryCipra Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Lovely quote. Where did you get it? Because it is absolutely correct. (Note: At first, Erdös famously thought switching couldn't matter, until he was shown a simulation that proved it did. Apparently, from your quote, he then considered why he was wrong. While it seems trivial, very few people do this, which is why I want to see where you got that quote.)

Yes, something is not correct in your proof. It is not a proof. It is a way to extend intuition from one case, to another, without resorting to actual logic. Sometimes you can get the right answer that way, but is it serendipity when you do.

For example, it is the same kind of reasoning that leads people to say "Since there are two doors left, and it was equally likely that the car was placed behind either, each now has a 50% chance." Unless your solution can show why this is an inferior solution - and not just that you got a different answer - it is not a proof. And the reason "probability paradoxes" like this continue, is because such non-proofs are considered acceptable if people believe they get the right answer.

What Erdös means in that quote, is that in order to prove the result, you need to compare the probabilities that the host would open Door #3 when (A) the car is behind Door #1, (B) the car is behind Door #2, or (C) the car is behind Door #3. Two of these are obvious: case (B) is 100%, and case (C) is 0%.

The point Erdös was making, is that the answer is determined entirely by how the host decides whether to open Door #2, or Door #3, in case (A). We were not told, explicitly, what that probability is, so we can only assume it is 50% (since the host could also have opened Door #2).

The proven (via Bayes' Theorem, which is why it is important) probability for each case, is its probability divided by the sum of all three (which is 150%). That is, (A) (50%)/(150%)=1/3, (B) (100%)/(150%)=2/3, and (C) (0%)/(150%)=0.

But what if we know that the host makes that decision in a biased way? It could be, say, 75%. Then the answers are (75%)/(175%)=3/7, (100%)/(175%)=4/7, and 0. Or - and this is more easily demonstrated - what if he always opens Door #3 if it has a goat? The the probability in case (A) is 100%, and the answers are (A) 1/2, (B) 1/2, and (C) 0. This is what Erdös implicitly assumed before he was shown the simulation, and the reason it is wrong is because it doesn't take the host's decision tree into account.